# LINQ Statement in VB.Net - What is it doing?

Tags: vb.net, linq, for-loop

I'm trying to understand what this LINQ statement is actually doing.  I have no experience in LINQ, so I'm trying to get somewhat of a "plain english" translation.

MyDataTable contains the following data:
OrderByValues, Contract, PayType, PayAmount

```
Dim groupIDs = From r In myds.MyDataTable Select OBV = r.Item("OrderByValues"), PT = r.Item("PayType"), Contract = r("Contract") Distinct
For Each r in groupIDS
   a = r.OBV
   b = r.PT
   c = r.Contract
Next
```

I'm not sure if there is enough info here to help you out or not.  I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the linq statement?

Comment: Start with basics, with MSDN documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line creates an query that will hold a collection of [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx).  The query is not executed yet because of [LINQ's deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).  This can be broken down into pieces:

- `From r In myds.MyDataTable` defines `r` as an individual element of the IEnumerable (usually array or List)) `myds.MyDataTable`
- `Select OBV = r.Item("OrderByValues"),  ... Distinct` creates an anonymous type with properties called `OBV`, `PT`, `Contract` and assigns those properties values from the element `r`.

The foreach loop actually executes the query and creates the IEnumerable to iterate over.  Then within this loop, it repeatedly sets `a`,`b`,`c` to the properties of the anonymous type defined in the query.  This does seem a bit strange, since the variables `a`,`b`,`c` will only remember the last value set to them.

More reading on [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx).

Comment: There was more to the code, I just stripped out a bunch for simplicity.  Thanks to all who commented.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all "OrderByValues", "PayType", and "Contract" columns from your datatable, ignoring duplicate rows.

It then iterates over the resultset, and assigns the 3 values to the variables "a", "b", and "c" respectively.

Comment: So is PT = r.Item("PayType") the same as PT = r("PayType")?

Comment: @SimpleMan In VB, yes.  `Item` is the default indexer, which VB allows you to omit, so `r("PayType")` is actually compiled to `r.Item("PayType")`.